# Why is this code considered a "possible 'System.InvalidOperationException'"?

Tags: c#, resharper, invalidoperationexception

Resharper suggested I change this code:

```
if (getBeginDate)
{
    return (DateTime)RptParamsFromDate;
}
```

...to this:

```
if (getBeginDate)
{
    if (RptParamsFromDate != null) return (DateTime)RptParamsFromDate;
}
```

...because, "*Possible 'System.InvalidOperationException'*" but when I accepted the suggested change, it doesn't compile, saying, "not all code paths return a value"

The "if" block has a following "else":

```
else
{
    int daysToAddToToDate = DateTime.DaysInMonth(RptParamsToDate.Value.Year, RptParamsToDate.Value.Month) - 1;
    RptParamsToDate = RptParamsToDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAddToToDate);
    return (DateTime)RptParamsToDate;
}
```

...so I don't know why it doesn't see the "else" as making sure a value is returned.

Comment: Both your `if` blocks need an `else` block, or there needs to be a return external to them both for all your code paths to return a value, right now you have no result if `getBeginDate` is true and `RptParamsFromDate` is null.

Comment: So, is your question about why that code could cause an InvalidOperationException, or why you're getting a build error after Resharper "fixes" it?

Comment: You're getting a "possible invalid operation exception" warning because it's not safe to cast a `null` to a `DateTime`.

Comment: "not all code paths return a value" Resharper error is associated with the `if (RptParamsFromDate != null) return (DateTime)RptParamsFromDate;` . Basically it highlights that you have not set a return value when `RptParamsFromDate` is `null`.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: There *is* an "else" block; it's shown above.

Comment: There is one else block. There needs to be two. As I stated, you have no return path if both `getBeginDate` is true and `RptParamsFromDate` is null. It would help to illustrate this if you include a complete snippet that demonstrates your issue, as one block of code.

Comment: @BJMyers: The latter; AFAICT, the "else" block should prevent the danger of no value being returned.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon The problem is that you now have *two* places where you need an else. As far as I can tell, you only handle the else for `!getBeginDate`, not for `getBeginDate && RptParamsFromDate == null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "else" **does not** make sure a value is returned in your example.

The method body:

```
if (getBeginDate)
{
    if (RptParamsFromDate != null) return (DateTime) RptParamsFromDate;
}
else
{
    int daysToAddToToDate = DateTime.DaysInMonth(RptParamsToDate.Value.Year, RptParamsToDate.Value.Month) - 1;
    RptParamsToDate = RptParamsToDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAddToToDate);
    return (DateTime)RptParamsToDate;
}
```

will return nothing when `getBeginDate` is true AND `RptParamsFromDate` is null.

A returning a default value at the end of the method body can solve this problem:

```
if (getBeginDate)
{
    if (RptParamsFromDate != null) return (DateTime) RptParamsFromDate;
}
else
{
    int daysToAddToToDate = DateTime.DaysInMonth(RptParamsToDate.Value.Year, RptParamsToDate.Value.Month) - 1;
    RptParamsToDate = RptParamsToDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAddToToDate);
    return (DateTime)RptParamsToDate;
}

DateTime defaultValue = DateTime.MinValue;//or what have you
return defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get "not all code paths return a value" is because of the if statements.
Only one of your if statements returns a path if the statement is false. You need to make **both** statements return a value

Example:

```
if (getBeginDate)
{
    if (RptParamsFromDate != null)
       return (DateTime)RptParamsFromDate;
    else 
    { 
        int daysToAddToToDate = DateTime.DaysInMonth(RptParamsToDate.Value.Year, RptParamsToDate.Value.Month) - 1;
        RptParamsToDate = RptParamsToDate.Value.AddDays(daysToAddToToDate);
        return (DateTime)RptParamsToDate;
    }
}
else { return null; }
```

Comment: "Cannot convert null to 'System.DateTime' because it is a non-nullable value type"

Comment: Then set it to somthing like DateTime.MinValue or DateTime.Now() or DateTime.MaxValue or DateTime.Today() it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so your problem can be replicated with the following:

```
void Main()
{
    DoSomething();
}
DateTime? MaybeGetDate()
{
    return null;
}
DateTime DoSomething()
{
    DateTime? test = MaybeGetDate();
    return (DateTime)test;
}
```

I'm not sure what type you have for `RptParamsFromDate`, but it's either a `Nullable<DateTime>` or a reference type. In other words, the warning about a possible invalid operation exception is because you may be trying to cast `null` to `DateTime`, which is not possible.

Now, Resharper is a bit confused, because it's default 'fix' is to simply check for null. But then you end up with this:

```
DateTime DoSomething()
{
    DateTime? test = MaybeGetDate();
    if (test != null)
        return (DateTime)test;
}
```

This should be clear as to why it doesn't compile - the method doesn't return *anything* if `test` is null. So you need to manually return a suitable `DateTime` in this case. That's something Resharper can't or won't help with. Perhaps `DateTime.MinValue` is a suitable candidate in this case.